# jfeinstein10 slidingmenu without using sherlockactionbar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

I would like to know how to include  jfeinstein10's slidingmenu in my project and i have no plan to use sherlockactionbar in my project. I have seen similar questions in stackoverflow but none them was clear to me.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: i loaded the library with sample project.. the sample application is using ABS i want to avoid it..

Comment: create new project in eclipse/androidStudio with latest build tools and api21... Choose new activity with slidingMenu... it will create one for you itself.